# Regex - How to extract value based on expression?

Tags: regex

Here's the string I am currently working with:
`"Key":"randomString01","Node":"01","Key":"randomString02","Node":"02","Key":"randomString03","Node":"03","Key":"randomString04","Node":"04",...`

I am trying to extract the `Key` value based on its `Node`.

This is what I have at the moment: `("Key":")(.*?)(","Node":"02")` (i.e. for `Node` `02`); however, this expression also includes the first `Key` & `Node`, which is not something I want.

That expression works fine with the first `Node`, but for the following ones, the regex returns all values.

Image (i.e. Node 02): https://prnt.sc/vtvafi => Desired value: `randomString02`

Image (i.e. Node 03): https://prnt.sc/vtvd2l => Desired value: `randomString03`

etc...

Comment: It looks like you're trying to parse JSON.  I suggest finding an existing code package or module that already exists to parse JSON and use that.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll take a look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```php
("Key":")([^"]*)(","Node":"02")
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/HvpqTy/1)

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    "Key":"                  '"Key":"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^"]*                    any character except: '"' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \3:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ","Node":"02"            '","Node":"02"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \3
```

Comment: Very interesting! It works, thanks a lot!